# jquery dynamically added checkbox not working with change() function

Tags: jquery, dynamic, checkbox, onchange

I dynamically load in a few li's that have a label and a checkbox in them to another visible ul. I set the checkboxes to be checked="checked" and i am trying to trigger an event to happen when i change these dynamically inserted checkboxes but nothing occurs.

Here is the jquery:

```
$(".otherProductCheckbox:checkbox").change( function(){
    alert('test');
});
```

Here is the html for the dynamically added li's:

```
<li class="otherProduct"><input type="checkbox" class="otherProductCheckbox radioCheck" checked="checked"/><label>Product Name</label></li>
```

Any idea why i cant get the alert to happen when the checkbox changes its checked state?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to use `liveQuery` or `live` to bind events to dynamically added elements.

```
$(".otherProductCheckbox:checkbox").live('change', function(){
    alert('test');
});
```

**EDIT**
To work in IE, you have to use click not change

```
$(".otherProductCheckbox:checkbox").live('click', function(){
        alert('test');
 });
```

Comment: @Teja Kantamneni: Perfect. Thanks for the direction. Still learning the ins and outs of jquery.

Comment: You're only required to do that if the elements are being added **after** the event handler has been set up.

Comment: @Gareth: yah that makes sense now.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't seem to be working in IE, works in Safari and FF... Any ideas?

Comment: Thats the issue with IE, IE will trigger change event only after the element looses the focus. http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/11/bug-193-onchange-does-not-fire-properly.html

Comment: For fix, use `click` instead of `change`

Comment: @Teja Kantamneni: That did the trick. Thank you again! Tricky stuff

Answer (score 20):

Since [live() is now deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/) as of jQuery 1.7, I thought I'd post the solution that worked for me on the same problem (trigger event when dynamically added checkboxes are changed).

```
$(document).on('click', '.otherProductCheckbox', function() {
    alert('test');
});
```

Comment: document.getElementById('id').live('click',function() {
    alert('test');
});
It is not working for me.. what "otherProductCheckbox" means here ?

Answer (score 0):

neither of the above worked for me, but this one worked when adding the checkbox dynamically for a list of items in a listview.

```
$('.favourite_itemList').on('click','.checkBox', function () {
   alert('test')
)};
```

Although no visible function/attribute change is shown in the particular checkbox element when optIn or optOut, the above code works well for me.